# Suse/GIT client doesn't access a Red Hat/GIT server

Tags: windows, git, redhat, suse

Two Windows client machines, running GIT clients can each get access to a GIT repository server that runs on a Red Hat server, take a repository and compile it. A Suse client, running a GIT client cannot get access to the same GIT repository running on the Red Hat server. The links between the three clients and the GIT server are direct, that is all the machines are on the same network, as pings show one hop only to jump from any of the three clients to the server. Does anybody of you have any idea as to what it could be ? A protocol problem, that is the Suse client doesn't have the right protocol installed on it ? Some wrong setting on the GIT client running on the Suse ? Any hint is very welcome. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "compile a repository"?

Comment: The client, that takes the repository, has the compiler that compiles the source code stored in the repository. For example, the repository has source code written in Java, so the client downloads locally the repository and then its Java compiler compiles locally the Java source code.

Comment: Add the configuration details of the clients to the question, please.

Comment: Hi, choroba. I'm not skillful enough to know how to get the kind of information I guess you need to have, like protocol(s) used by the Suse machine, and which port(s) these protocol(s) use(s). You knwo what, one of the two Windows  clients is reachable through http://c8088sq1/ , but I don't know how to get further, while I'm afraid you cannot even show the Apache Tomcat page through that link. Do you know what cmd commands should I use in order to get the information you need ? I could try and use them to see if I'm able to collect some data useful to you.